ESP8266 Connecting output to VCC via LED & resistor
Most circuits I've seen for connecting an LED to an output PIN connect the LED to ground (via a resistor).
I would like to connect the LED to VCC (via a resistor). Is there any harm in doing this?
What I'm trying to do is to use 4 GPIO output PINs to control 4 LEDs but also have a single physical switch to enable a user of my device to turn all the LEDs off if they don't like the glow.

There's nothing wrong with that, since the MCU outputs are push-pull, and can source current as well as they can sink it. That wasn't that case in the past, when everything was TTL, but CMOS is a different story. Either of these is fine (provided your resistors are chosen such that output current constraints are respected):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The only problem you might have is that when the switch is open, and some outputs are high while others are low, leakage current through the reverse biased diodes may actually be enough to cause the others to glow very dimly. Try this, in the dark, to see if that's a problem:

simulate this circuit


I would like to connect the LED to VCC (via a resistor).

This is called "current sinking" or "sinking drive".

Is there any harm in doing this?

No, as long as the current is kept below the "current sink" rating of the GPIO pin.
You have two options:

You can configure the GPIO pin as a push-pull output: The pin will connect the GPIO pin to either the GND or the VDD of the ESP so the LED will glow when the output is zero (GND).
You can configure the GPIO pin as open-drain (Hi-Z) output: The GPIO pin will either connect to the GND or be floating. When floating, the pin voltage will be close to the VCC (LED side). If it's higher than the VDD of the ESP it can harm the pin. If you use the same voltage rail for both the LED and the ESP it's fine.


Not only is there nothing wrong with driving an LED + resistor between the MCU's Vdd (in this case Vio) and GPIO, it's the preferred way to do it.
Most MCU GPIO pins sink current considerably better than they source it, because N-channel MOSFETs of the same size are much better than P-channel MOSFETs of the same size, due to physics.
For example, if you refer to the Espressif ESP8266 datasheet you'll see that voltage drop when sourcing current (0.66V with a 3.3V supply) is twice as high as when sinking current (0.33V with a 3.3V supply), presumably at the same 12mA output current:

Especially with something like a blue or white LED this could make a big difference in the brightness.
